# Python: I am getting Errors while running Python Unittest

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

I am using following python version

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0
```

Python folder contains only following 4

```
IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit)
Python 3.8 (32-bit)
Python 3.8 Manuals (32-bit)
Python 3.8 Module Docs (32-bit)
```

I have following unit test in test_sum_unittest.py

```
import unittest


class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum([1, 2, 3]), 6, "Should be 6")

    def test_sum_tuple(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum((1, 2, 2)), 6, "Should be 6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Ran test with

```
python test_sum_unittest.py
```

The Error logs are as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sum_unittest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .result import TestResult
  File "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\unittest\result.py", line 5, in <module>
    import traceback
  File "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "C:\Users\ali\Flasky\Automation\token.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

What is wrong there ?

### any help would be appreciate, I had earlier python2.7 and I can see in tht folder I have many folder i.e. libs, scripts, Lib, Doc, Dlls, tcl, tools but thing such in python 3.8.0

update now I have installed python 3.5 and still it gives following error

OK Now I have reinstalled python 3-5-1 and  folder seems  to contain everything but  still it gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sum_unittest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "unittest\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "unittest\result.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ali\Flasky\Automation\token.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves import queue
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 91, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "queue.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "dummy_threading.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "threading.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'format_exc'
```

Any help will be appreciated

Br

Sara

Comment: try installing requests? (`pip install requests`). EDIT: looks like you messed up your Python installation. Reinstall python, should do the trick.

Comment: @Alex Bodnya which version should I install ?

Comment: @AlexBodnya which Python should I install, I tried 3.5 and still same, I dont find any folders after installion and when I type commane 
'python --version' it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Install `request`:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: I don't think it would help. It seems Python installation was messed up for some reason.

Comment: @Harsha Biyani I have following
pip list                                                                                                              Package    Version
---------- ----------
certifi    2019.11.28
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.8
pip        19.3.1
requests   2.22.0
setuptools 41.2.0
urllib3    1.25.7

Comment: @Sara Do you have more than 1 python version installed in your system?

Comment: @Harsha Biyani, yes python 2.7 and 3.5, I installed 3.5 because I read in some forum which said support for 2.7 has ended and this isnatlled 3.5

Comment: yes. agree. Python 2's support is going to end soon. So it means, `pip` and `requests` get installed for python 2. That's why you seeing missing error for `requests` package

Comment: @HarshaBiyani ok I have deleted 2.7 and now I still get same error here are logs 
File "test_sum_unittest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "unittest\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "unittest\result.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>

Comment: @HarshaBiyani
File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves import queue
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 91, in __get__

Comment: install packages using `pip3` like: `pip3 install requests`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani
C:\Users\ali\Flasky\Automation>pip3 install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-p

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I have added site -packages into path too but still same.

Comment: `pip3` get installed with python3 itself. You can check all packages installed using: `pip3 freeze` command.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I can se clearly, unittest is missing

Comment: So it means: packages are installed. Try to run test case with python 3. Ex: `python3 test_sum_unittest.py`

Comment: @HarshaBiyani here is result of pip3 freeze
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.7
Werkzeug==0.16.0

Comment: import `format_exc ` in python3 like: `from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc`

Comment: ok I have now installed unittest3 but now it gives following eror

File "test_sum_unittest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest2
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\unittest2\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from unittest2.collector import collector
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\unittest2\collector.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unittest2.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "C:\python-3.5.3\lib\site-packages\unittest2\loader.py", line 6, in <module>
    import traceback

Comment: @HarshaBiyani ok now I can see this link: https://pypi.org/project/unittest2/ which say
unittest2 includes a very basic setuptools compatible test collector. Specify test_suite = 'unittest2.collector' in your setup.py

Comment: @HarshaBiyani ok I have sorted out this problem and prolem was that in my directory I had a file with name token.py, I renamed it and everything started wirking, Hell now how someone on planet earth can find out that this could be the reason but I am happy it is working now, thankyou tho.

Answer (score 0):

ok I have sorted out this problem and problem was that in my directory I had a file with name token.py, I renamed it and everything started working, Hell now how someone on planet earth can find out that this could be the reason but I am happy it is working now, thankyou everyone tho.

Comment: The Python standard library has a [module called `token`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/token.html).  Chances are, something in the Python standard library had an import statement like `import token` which imported *your* token module, rather than the standard library one.

Comment: @NicholasM verymuch possible or that was the reason and honestly I dont have any experience with python, so it took me 24 hours trying many things bu finally I am happy